# Part 2. dodge overheating

Tags: dodge

I have a 2002 Dodge Ram 1500 with a 4.7 liter the condenser fan isnt coming on does anybody know why it would not come on

Comment: I'm going to repeat myself here. The condenser fan has NOTHING to do with the truck overheating. It only has to do with the air conditioning. Are you having an air conditioning problem or a overheating problem?

Comment: Okay I'm going to repeat myself here now my truck has a condenser fan that also comes on when the truck gets warm if it's starting to get hot to cool it off that's the only fan my truck has and I've had this truck for 6 years so I know when that fan comes on and I'm not using my AC that it's cooling my truck off

Comment: @vini_i Dennis might be correct, in some cars there is only one FAN for both engine cooling as well as the air con.

Answer (score 0):

In a regular car the radiator and condenser are usually directly on top of each other and have only a single fan for both. In 2002 Dodge Ram 1500 4.7L the hood areas is so wide that the radiator and condenser are next to each other and each has their own fan. See picture.
[image]
The radiator should have a mechanical fan that sits in the middle and the condenser should have an electric fan that cools just the condenser.